# Matching users with objects based on keywords and activity in Ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm, keyword

I have users that have authenticated with a social media site. Now based on their last X (let's say 200) posts, I want to map how much that content matches up with a finite list of keywords.

What would be the best way to do this to capture associated words/concepts (maybe that's too difficult) or just get a score of how much, say, my tweet history maps to 'Walrus' or 'banana'?

Would a naive Bayes work here to separate into 'matches' and 'no match'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python I would say NLTK can easily do it. In Ruby maybe gem called [lda-ruby](https://github.com/ealdent/lda-ruby/) will help you. Whole LDA concept is well explained [here](http://blog.echen.me/2011/08/22/introduction-to-latent-dirichlet-allocation/) - look at Sarah Palin's email for example. There's even the example of an app (not entirely in Ruby, but still) which did that -> github.com/echen/sarah-palin-lda

Or maybe I just say stupid things and that can't help you at all. I'm not an expert ;)

Answer (score 1):

A simple bayes would work in this case, it is highly used to detect if emails are spam or not so for a simple keyword matching it should work pretty well.

For this problem you could also apply a recommendation system where you look for the top recommended keyword for a user (or for a post).

There are a ton of ways for doing this. I would recommend you to read [Programming Collective Intelligence](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596529325). It is explained using python but since you know ruby there should be not problem to understand the code.